# spring clear session scope bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have created a bean of session scope as per below:

```java
@Bean
@Scope(
    value = WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_SESSION,
    proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public TodoList todos() {
    return new TodoList();
}
```

I have added the bean as a model attribute and I could display the beans across multiple pages.

```java
@GetMapping("/todos.html")
public String list(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("todos", todos);
    return "scopedproxytodos";
}
```

But I am not sure of how to clear the attribute in the session.

```java
@PostMapping("/end")
public ModelAndView endSession(SessionStatus sessionStatus, Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("todos", new TodoList());
    sessionStatus.setComplete();
    return new ModelAndView("redirect:/");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have added the bean as a model attribute and I could display the
> beans across multiple pages :
>
> ...
>
> ```
> `model.addAttribute("todos", todos);`
> ```
>
> ...

Not really. That adds the attribute only in the current view.

To achieve that you should annotate your `TodoList` class with `@SessionScope` such as :

```
@SessionScope
@Component
public class TodoList {
    // ...
}
```

Then annotate your controllers that need to have a conversational scope for `todos` with `@SessionAttributes` and inject that with `@ModelAttribute`. Not tested but something like that :

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes("todos")
public class FooController { 

  @GetMapping("/todos.html")
  public String list(@ModelAttribute TodoList todos) {
    // set the todos value
    return "scopedproxytodos";
  }

}
```

You can use that in any other controller annotated with `@SessionAttributes("todos")`.

And to remove `todos` of the current conversation session, use  `status.setComplete()` as you did.
In your case you can just remove that :

```
@PostMapping("/end")
public ModelAndView endSession(SessionStatus sessionStatus, Model model) {
    sessionStatus.setComplete();
    return new ModelAndView("redirect:/");
}
```

And let the controller with the conversational scope to reinit it as you want (`FooController` does that actually).
An alternative way is reinitializing that instead of removing that.
For example :

```
@PostMapping("/end")
public ModelAndView endSession(@ModelAttribute TodoList todos) {
    todos.clear();
    return new ModelAndView("redirect:/");
}
```

The advantage of this solution :

- neater / less verbose
- not needed to create beans for each session. Beans are more expensive in terms of overhead than values stored in the session.

[More information here about that way of manipulate conversational attributes.](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-factory-scopes-session)

---

The [`SessionStatus`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/support/SessionStatus.html) class manages the attributes of the spring session :

> Simple interface that can be injected into handler methods, allowing
> them to signal that their session processing is complete. The handler
> invoker may then follow up with appropriate cleanup, e.g. of session
> attributes which have been implicitly created during this handler's
> processing

It means that it clears the attributes stored in the Spring handler session (that is different from a classic http session), not the attributes stored in the http requests and actually you didn't add anything in the spring session attributes.
So that is useless.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your detailed reply. I appreciate it. Please correct me if I am wrong. sessionattributes is an alternative way of doing it. But still how to clear that session scoped bean?

Comment: You are welcome. Spring Beans and Spring attributes may have both a scope session but are two distinct things. The spring bean `todos` will not be cleared while the http session is not. That's why you should not use that for conversational requirement.